# DOM Parser strips out vuejs-attributes

Tags: php, dom

I am using Masterminds/html5-php (https://github.com/Masterminds/html5-php/) to modify the content of my HTML-output.

Unfortunately, the vue-js attribute `@submit.prevent="save | valid"` is being removed after processing:

Original

```
<form id="formmaker-form" class="uk-form {{ formitem.data.formStyle }} {{ formitem.data.classSfx }}"
      v-validator="form" @submit.prevent="save | valid" v-cloak>
</form>
```

Processed:

```
<form id="formmaker-form" class="uk-form {{ formitem.data.formStyle }} {{ formitem.data.classSfx }}" v-validator="form" v-cloak>
</form>
```

My code:

```
public function __construct(HTML5 $htmlParser = null)
{
    $this->htmlParser = $htmlParser ?: new HTML5();
}
public function fix($markup, $topLevel = 1, $depth = 6)
{
    if ( ! $this->isFullHtmlDocument($markup)) {
        $partialID = 'toc_generator_' . mt_rand(1000, 4000);
        $markup = sprintf("<body id='%s'>%s</body>", $partialID, $markup);
    }

    $domDocument = $this->htmlParser->loadHTML($markup);
    $domDocument->preserveWhiteSpace = true; // do not clobber whitespace

    $sluggifier = new UniqueSluggifier();

    /** @var \DOMElement $node */
    foreach ($this->traverseHeaderTags($domDocument, $topLevel, $depth) as $node) {
        if ($node->getAttribute('id')) {
            continue;
        }

        $node->setAttribute('id', $sluggifier->slugify($node->getAttribute('title') ?: $node->textContent));
    }

    return $this->htmlParser->saveHTML((isset($partialID)) ? $domDocument->getElementById($partialID)->childNodes : $domDocument);
}
```

As I can not use another class (html5-php is part of a dependency I use) I have to continue using that.

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You may replace problematic attribute to some safe name, and reverse it after everything.

```
public function fix($markup, $topLevel = 1, $depth = 6) {
    $markup = str_replace('@submit.prevent', md5('@submit.prevent'), $markup);

    // do your magic

    return str_replace(md5('@submit.prevent'), '@submit.prevent', $markup);
}
```